# `You must call .manage() before using this command` when calling simple tauri function from js part

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rust, tauri

I'm curently working on a Tauri React/typescript app and got an error while i use tauri function. When i call the function `init_project` the program crash with this error :

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'state not managed for field `state` on command `init_project`. You must call .manage() before using this command', /home/korocouille/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tauri-1.2.4/src/state.rs:51:7
note: run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Here is the Taruri function :

```rust
#[tauri::command]
pub fn init_project(state: tauri::State<InternalStudioState>, root_folder: &str) -> Result<StudioState, APIError> {
    Ok(StudioState::sample())
}
```

Here the call of this function :

```js
export async function invokeInitProject(path: string): Promise<StudioState> {
  const res = await invoke<StudioState>("init_project", {
    root_folder: path
  }).catch((err) => {
    throw err;
  });
  console.log(res);
  return res;
}
```

And the main :

```rust
fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .manage(InternalStudioState::new())
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![
            api::commands::studio_state,
            api::commands::load_project,
            api::commands::load_project_with_view,
            api::commands::init_project,
            api::commands::init_project_with_view,
            api::commands::up_to_date,
            api::commands::root_folder,
            api::commands::reload_project,
            api::commands::view_kind,
            api::commands::current_view,
            api::commands::switch_view,
            api::commands::project_name,
            api::commands::set_project_name,
            ])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

The Tauri part is actually simple and the only things `init_project` do is to return a pre defined sample so i don't have much idea to find out why this error hapen

Comment: Strange. Are you sure `InternalStudioState::new()` returns an instance of `InternalStudioState` and not maybe `Result<InternalStudioState, Error>` or `Option<InternalStudioState>`?

Answer (score -1):

The probleme came from an import in the main file.
I just remove this `use ireflex_studio::api::{types::{ProjectViewRootNode, StudioState}, commands::InternalStudioState};` to this `use ireflex_studio::api::commands;`